# Ruby - rspec how to include specs in root of project?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

rspec always finds files in the `spec/` directory tree.

How can I have it also find files that are in the root of the project (the one that contains the `spec/` folder iself.

For example if I have a small project with only two tests, any folders may essentially be unneeded overhead given a minimalist approach.  Or if you only have one type of test and would only create one folder it may not (or may) be worth creating that one folder or just omitting it altogether.  The value it adds of course is immediate description of what type of tests exist, even if only one type exist.

Answer (score 1):

Spec supports a [--default-path](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-8/docs/configuration/setting-the-default-spec-path) option, and [you can put a default set of command-line options into an .rspec file](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-8/docs/configuration/read-command-line-configuration-options-from-files).  That is, you can create a `.rspec` file in your project root directory containing

```
--default-path .
```

My experience has generally been that rspec tests are almost always in a `spec` directory; I would be a little surprised to see them in a top-level directory.  This in particular mirrors the [standard gem filesystem layout](https://guides.rubygems.org/what-is-a-gem/) which puts all library code into a `lib` directory and tests in a parallel `spec` directory.

Answer (score 0):

One approach:

```
# File: spec_helper.rb  Add the following at the top:

Dir.glob(File.expand_path("../../*_spec.rb", __FILE__)).each do |file|
  require file
end
```

This will include files at the root to the ones already being included in `spec/`